# Javascript: Determining Nearest element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am looking to find TextArea element(Arrow in Gold/Yellow color) using label element(in red color arrow). I use `getBoundingClientRect` api to find the center of each element on the page.

*Note I am filtering out specific input elements and textareas on page along with label element to restrict my search to specific elements on page.
So my filtered elements includes only elements marked with arrows in picture.*

Here is code I have tried

```
//Label (Arrow Red in picture)
label_rect = $("label[for='textarea']").getBoundingClientRect()
//Calculating Center Coordinates
label_rect_x = label_rect.x + label_rect.width / 2 // X Coordinate
label_rect_y = label_rect.y + label_rect.height / 2 // Y Coordinate
// TextArea(Arrow Gold/Yellow in picture)
txbox_rect = $("#textarea").getBoundingClientRect()
//Calculating Center Coordinates
txbox_rect_x = txbox_rect.x + txbox_rect.width / 2 // X Coordinate
txbox_rect_y = txbox_rect.y + txbox_rect.height / 2  // Y Coordinate
// Calculating Distance two centers
txbox_rect_dis = Math.sqrt(
    (txbox_rect_x - label_rect_x) * (txbox_rect_x - label_rect_x) +
    (txbox_rect_y - label_rect_y) * (txbox_rect_y - label_rect_y)
    )
console.log(txbox_rect_dis)
//Number Box(Arrow Blue in picture)
numbox_rect = $("#in").getBoundingClientRect()
//Calculating Center Coordinates
numbox_rect_x = numbox_rect.x + numbox_rect.width / 2 // X Coordinate
numbox_rect_y = numbox_rect.y + numbox_rect.height / 2  // Y Coordinate
// Calculating Distance two centers
numbox_rect_dis = Math.sqrt(
    (numbox_rect_x - label_rect_x) * (numbox_rect_x - label_rect_x) +
    (numbox_rect_y - label_rect_y) * (numbox_rect_y - label_rect_y)
    )
console.log(numbox_rect_dis)
```

This code seemed to work for most of the use cases, but recently with these elements in picture I noticed, nearest element is calculated as number box(blue arrow in picture) and not textarea(gold arrow in picture).
I really cannot figure out what is going wrong here or is there something fundamental that needs to be fixed here?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to calculate this like that? Can't you simply link your <label> element to your <textarea> by other means like for instance the specs defined [`for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes)? Relying on mouse position is prone to get things wrong. Just think of users from a screen-reader, what do you think x, y means to them? And if you really want us to explain why in that case it was already failing, we would need to see the markup and the styles applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

So The solution was to not add width & height to calculate center of the element. This is necessary since elements can be of different sizes resulting in unpredictable behaviour